# Trouble displaying profile pictures

Tags: discussion, bug, images, user-profile

For a few days I am noticing that the profile picture of many users is not displayed correctly.

I see [image] alot.

Yesterday I had terrible internet connection, so I thought it was me. But it is still there.
Could still be me. Could be a new trend I am not getting.

Comment: It has been noticed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356397/gravatars-not-loaded-for-certain-sources).

Comment: This might be also related: [Default profile picture from Facebook is being displayed, instead of Facebook picture if a user joined before Stack using Facebook API v2+](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355805) I have seen mention of this on MathOverflow Meta: [Why did my profile picture disappear?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4748)

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356397/380081

Answer (score 6):

I get that too. Started noticing it a few months ago. The few I investigated seemed to be hosted "off-site", like the URLs for the `<img>` tag was on a Facebook server, or some non-Stackexchange place like that.

Me, I've got all kinds of Javascript disabled and hosts blocked, so I figured it was due to that. Do you have any kind of blocking enabled?

Comment: I have add-block enabled. :-) José Carlos Santos brought to my attention that this has been noticed. So I am fine with that.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote my answer before his comment.  Sounds like it is being dealt with. I wonder if my problem will go away too when your problem is fixed?